# TypeScript type with specific set of keys and values

Tags: typescript

## Updated Version

Full Playground here

[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgB...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwNIRAZygXigCIBDIqAH2ICNyqiBjIgbgChXRIoAhEnCACrgIAHgFQIAD2AQAdmjzwkqTNhwA%20AlADerKFE4QAXFAFsAvu0NQAsiADy1AFYQGwIZADiAVxIAnNC1dfQBtcQBLWVgEFHQsXABdE15%20D1EBdVZLVgB6HNMAC3C8YqhkApJgKABJKBIAWzrw%20siAczrgVkiZPwAzEgZoO0cXNwlpOQVbB2dXd2Eff0DgupNtA2ETUnJzKAAyHShexEQt48Qdtn1qNY3ILdooXYP16n8H-0uoPSgGW8MtkwnvtDm8AF4fMGXLLsPJQAByKBqvxIslkiCqAwY4TQcmAJAQICg3n4BgK0GQfkQsnab1JhhwXVkPX6g2mIzmACZxjJ5HhhrM3GlFgEdD8SP9NjQdiD1uczidoddJfdpcCXlA3n4Pn4vj8-ocAcQgc9QSQITRzdDsnD7H5iaSGIh6mA4BAZHAiZTqe0GRIAG5yJksgZDGajYAAZh5k354bmwt8opWEsO8uI5yVmpVxjVpte70tuqezG%20%20gN6yNjBlGvBkOtsPy3G8VVqDFRUBwwHCCCgLRweBIUAA1thgxA%20qH2YLgAAWGN86cRxNLMX6VOVqXbdVpk4Ki4ln43Q1bx75zWFohavU2-IweTI9tRLs9uB1NCBfzUcLAPz%20Ildt4vS9OOk5sgKEYAKwLlMEEJgsSbLOKOZbGQO5ynuGaKoeyonqqV41ma2pFnq5YocahEFhaV5WjhRwnLwxE0VCFhAA)

I am trying to create an object type that only allows specific keys, but for each key you must extend a specific generic type as value. I.e.

```js
type AllowedKeys = "a" | "b" | "c";

type MyGenericType<T extends AllowedKeys> = {
  type: T;
}

type MyObjectTypeGuard = {
  [T in AllowedKeys]: MyGenericType<T>
}

// This is what I am aiming at, I tried to make sure that I now have an interface the should prevent me from using the only allowed keys with the allowed values
interface MyObject extends MyObjectTypeGuard {
  a: { type: "a" } & { foo: "foo" };
  b: { type: "b" } & { bar: "bar" }; 
  c: { type: "c" } & { baz: "baz" };
}
```

Now that prevents me from using keys with the wrong values

```js
// I cannot accidentially use the wrong base types
interface MyObject2 extends MyObjectTypeGuard {
  a: { type: "b" } & { foo: "foo" };
  b: { type: "b" } & { bar: "bar" }; 
  c: { type: "c" } & { baz: "baz" };
}

// Or use completely wrong types even
interface MyObject3 extends MyObjectTypeGuard {
  a: { foo: "foo" };
  b: { type: "b" } & { bar: "bar" }; 
  c: { type: "c" } & { baz: "baz" };
}
```

But I can still do other things that I want myself to prevent from

```js
// But I can still miss a key
interface MyObject4 extends MyObjectTypeGuard {
  a: { type: "a" } & { foo: "foo" };
  b: { type: "b" } & { bar: "bar" }; 
}

// And I can still add arbitrary stuff
interface MyObject5 extends MyObjectTypeGuard {
  a: { type: "a" } & { foo: "foo" };
  b: { type: "b" } & { bar: "bar" }; 
  c: { type: "c" } & { baz: "baz" };
  fooBar: "baz";
}
```

I am looking for a way to define an object type / interface that forces me to use all keys (and only those) and has me extend a specific generic type for each value

## Old version

> We have a base model `BodyNode` which can be extended into variants:
>
> ````js
> type BodyNode<T extends NodeType> = {   readonly type: T; };
>
> type NodeWithText<T extends NodeType> = BodyNode<T> & WithText; type
> NodeWithChildren<T extends NodeType> = BodyNode<T> & WithChildren;
> type NodeWithReference<T extends NodeType> = BodyNode<T> &
> WithReference;
>
> interface WithText {   readonly text: string; }
>
> interface WithChildren {   readonly children: Node[]; }
>
> interface WithReference {   readonly href: string; } ```
>
> to be able to iterate over the node types, we created an interface
> that maps `NodeType`s to variants
>
> types:
>
> ```typescript type BodyNodes = {   [T in NodeType]: BodyNode<T>; };
>
> interface Nodes extends BodyNodes {   headline: NodeWithText;  
> paragraph: NodeWithChildren;   anchor: NodeWithReference; }
>
> type Node = Nodes[keyof Nodes]; ```
>
> implementation:
>
> ```tsx type Components = {   [K in BodyNode]: React.FC<{ node:
> Nodes[K] }>; };
>
> const components: Components = {   headline: Headline,   paragraph:
> Paragraph,   anchor: Anchor, };
>
> const Body = (props: { nodes: Node[] }) => (   <div>
>     {props.nodes.map(node => {
>       const Component = components[node.type];
>       return <Component node={node} />;
>     })}   </div> ); ```
>
> we are using the node types as keys for the `Nodes` as well as the
> `Components` and with this we can map the Nodes with the right types
> to the right components in type safe way.
>
> But this implementation has a big flaw:
>
> ```typescript type BodyNodes = {   [T in NodeType]: BodyNode<T>; };
>
> interface Nodes extends BodyNodes {   headline: BodyNode<'headline'>; 
> paragraph: BodyNode<'headline'>;   //                     ^^^^^^^^
> this will cause an error, which is what we want   anchor:
> BodyNode<'anchor'>;   yadda: 'foobar';   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is
> still possible because we can extend BodyNodes in   //                
> any way and that's not cool } ```
>
> We'd love to find a way to write a type that allows only
>
> - specific keys as above
> - for specific keys only specific values as above
> - requires each key to be there
> - BUT forbids extending, ie. have an exact implementaition of that type and nothing else
> ````

Comment: Your first definition of `Nodes` does not compile because it mentions `NodeWithText`, `NodeWithChildren`, and `NodeWithReference` which are generic types that need type parameters.  Could you try to make sure your code constitutes a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  The minimum example probably has less code also: if [this](https://tsplay.dev/4Wy3AN) is what you're looking for, for example

Comment: Hey @jcalz thanks, silly me, always do the same mistakes. I completely updated my question and added a link to a ts playground at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with interfaces: the 'extends' always means you can extend.  However how about what's below?  It's a little clunky since we're defining our new type inside <>, but I think it does what you want.

```
type AllowedKeys = "a" | "b" | "c";

type MyGenericType<T extends AllowedKeys> = {
    type: T;
}

type MyObjectTypeGuard = { [T in AllowedKeys]: MyGenericType<T> };

type VerifyType<T extends MyObjectTypeGuard &
    { [U in Exclude<keyof T, AllowedKeys>]: never }> = T;

// Incorrect type letters or missing 'type', additional properties,
// and missing properties lead to errors
type VerifiedType = VerifyType<{
    a: { type: "a" } & { foo: "foo" };
    b: { type: "b" } & { bar: "bar" };
    c: { type: "c" } & { baz: "baz" };
}>;

const obj: VerifiedType = {
    a: { type: "a", foo: "foo" },
    b: { type: "b", bar: "bar" },
    c: { type: "c", baz: "baz" }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!